# .NET Custom Console

Tags: c#, .net, console

I'm seriously perplex at how this guy make the console do this. This being it doesn't write top down, and how he can move up and down like that....

Can it be done with MonoDev and Terminal?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MA0nscgV2U

Comment: "Can it be done with MonoDev and Terminal?" I'm not .NET expert, but my wild guess would be yes. Google? :)

Comment: C# doesn't have anything to do with the Console. You meant ".NET"

Comment: I wasen't sure if terminal would allow the same things as command prompt. Like colors are different...

Comment: To be quite honest, I'm a tad surprised this kind of thing impresses people these days... This brings back memories of BBSs (especially the movies in TradeWars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) class has a `SetCursorPosition` method, as well as `ForegroundColor` and `BackgroundColor` properties.

The documentation for [`System.ConsoleColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor.aspx) has an example of using colors.

Answer (score 1):

The youtube video has a download link for the .exe and this is a [link](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to reflector :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either the [`Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console_members.aspx) class, or p/invoke to the Win32 [`Console API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682087(VS.85).aspx). (Same one the  .Net `Console` class uses internally)

Don't know if Mono has implementation of the `Console` class (though fully expect them to do) or if it supports p/invoke style calls to native Linux/Unix APIs (though I do expect them to do :-)), but certainly Terminal does support direct access to the screen buffer. So it should be doable on non-Windows platforms as well.